# Orthogonality relation in $L^2$ implying periodicity

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integration, curves-and-surfaces

Let $\theta(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ be two real $C^1$ functions $[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let us assume $\theta$ has the properties
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\theta(t)} dt=0. 
$$
Geometrically this means that the curve obtained by integrating the (tangent) vector function $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ over $(0,2\pi)$ is closed. I would like to prove the following claim

> If the integral 
>   $$
> \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(\theta(t)+\lambda\phi(t))} dt=0
> $$
>   for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ than $\phi$ is periodic of period $2\pi/l$ with $1\neq l\in\mathbb{N}$.

Note that the function $F(\lambda):=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(\theta(t)+\lambda\phi(t))} dt$ is analytic in $\lambda$ and therefore it is constantly equal to $0$ iff its derivatives $F^{(n)}(0)=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(\theta(t))} (\phi(t))^n dt$ vanish for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

OBSERVATION. If $\frac{d}{dt}\theta$ and $\phi$ are periodic of common period $\frac{2\pi}{l}$ with $1\neq l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{l}} e^{i\theta}\neq 0$ then the converse implication is true. In fact, in this setting $\theta=c\cdot t+\theta_p(t)$ with $c=\frac{2\pi}{l}(\theta(\frac{2\pi}{l})-\theta(0))$
and $\theta_p$ periodic of period $\frac{2\pi}{l}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(\theta(t)+\lambda\phi(t))} dt &=& \sum_{j=0}^{l-1} \int_{j \frac{2\pi}{l}}^{(j+1) \frac{2\pi}{l}} e^{i(c\cdot t+\theta_p(t)+\lambda\phi(t))} dt \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^{l-1} e^{i\cdot j \cdot \frac{2\pi}{l}} \int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{l}} e^{i(c\cdot t+\theta_p(t)+\lambda\phi(t))} dt,
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality is obtained by repetedly applying the substitution $t'=t-\frac{2\pi}{l}$. Since we know $\sum_{j=0}^{l-1} e^{i\cdot j \cdot \frac{2\pi}{l}} \int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{l}} e^{i\theta(t)}dt=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\theta(t)} dt=0$ then also the integral above must be $0$.

Comment: Is it not true that if $\phi$ is constant then $\theta$ can be any function satisfying the original conditions?

Comment: Or if $\phi$ has even period, any $\theta$ with $\theta(t+\pi) = -\theta(t)$ would work.

Comment: For the first comment, yes. This is providing a rotation of the original curve by changing the parameter I start measuring the turning angle from. You are right, my formulation include also this trivial case, which is something I do not want to consider. I am going to edit it.

Comment: Concerning the second comment, good point. Can one at least deduce the periodicity of $\phi$ of some non-trivial period $2\pi/l$?

Comment: The question has become a moving target, so I'm not going to think about it more.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Should I have phrased the new question in another post?

Comment: Yes, creating a new post is generally preferred over changing the question after getting the answer you didn't want. But before you do that you might spend a little time thinking about the problem on your own, now that you understand why the original question had a negative answer...

Comment: It looks like (though I haven't checked the details) there are ways to move 6 points on the circle in a non-trivial way so that the sum of the vectors times their speeds is always $0$. Then if $\psi$ is constant on each such sextet (but otherwise arbitrary), you get a counterexample.

Comment: If I get your idea right, you are talking about deforming a circle, so $\theta(t)=t$. In this setting, if we drop for a moment the hypotesis of $\phi$ being continuous and take it as piecewise constant then what we are deforming is basically a polyline with as many edges as the pieces on which $\phi$ is defined and that for $\lambda=0$ is a polygon inscribed in the circle. Your claim is that there are choices for its angles that guarantee the linkage remains closed for all choices of $\lambda$?

Comment: Yeah. Something like that though the picture I had in mind was slightly different. Let me know if you still want a detailed description :)

Comment: I actually would like to understand your idea better. I saw you also commented on the new phrasing of the problem (which is now restricted to analytic functions). Can you plese give a more explicit description of the function $\phi$ you have in mind and explain a bit why this guarantees the curve is closed no matter the stretch $\lambda$? Would this solution work also in the analytic setting? Thanks!