# Reparametrization of a closed curve that balances sum of first derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, fourier-analysis, integration, curves-and-surfaces

(Question in the yellow box below.)

A few weeks ago I was wondering about the existence of a scalar function $f(s): S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a turning angle $\phi(s):S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/[0,2\pi)$ such that $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} f(s)^n e^{i \phi(s)} ds=0.
$$
These can be constructed by considering functions $g(t),\theta(t): S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/[0,2\pi)$, with $g$ increasingly monotone, and for which $\exists$ $N$ such that $\forall$ $t\in\big[0,\frac{2\pi}{N}\big)$ the following sum is balanced
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} g'\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)e^{i\theta\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)}=0.
$$
In fact, for any $\bar{f}$ of period $\frac{2\pi}{N}$, $\forall$ $n$
$$
0=\int\limits_0^{\frac{2\pi}{N}} \bar{f}(t)^n \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} g'\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)e^{i\theta\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)} dt=\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \bar{f}\big(g^{-1}(s)\big)^n e^{i\theta\left(g^{-1}(s)\right)}ds.
$$
In the answer to [Does $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\theta(t)} (\phi(t))^n dt=0$ $\forall \; n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ imply $\phi$ periodic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334186/does-int-02-pi-ei-thetat-phitn-dt-0-forall-n-in-mathbbn) fedja gave a nice construction of analytic functions with these properties for $N=3$.

Now I would like to reverse this construction and answer the following question

> Given an analytic arc-length parametrized closed curve $\gamma(s):S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with turning angle function $\phi(s)$, under what conditions can one find an analytic reparametrization $\alpha(t):S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall$ $t \in \big[0,\frac{2\pi}{N}\big)$
>   $$
> \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \alpha'\!\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)\, \gamma'\!\bigg(\alpha\!\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)\bigg) =\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \alpha'\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right) e^{i\phi\big(\alpha\left(t+j\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)\big)} = 0? 
> $$

Does anyone have some hints on how to tackle the problem? Note that if $N$ is large then the sum in which we are interested becomes uniformly small also for the arc-length parametrization itself so we can sort of get as close as we want to the solution this way but at some point we have to start working with $N$ fixed. I tried to follow this path but I am currently stuck.

I am also interested in the same problem (maybe slightly easier) for closed curve of class $C^n$.

Thank you.